# Installation of Python

Tags: python

Want to use `python` and typed the command `py` which gave me the following list.

I certainly want to use the most recent version.  Should one clean up such setup so that I only have `python3.6`  ?

```
hagbard@fuckup:~$ py
py3clean      pydoc         pygettext2.7  python        python3.6m
py3compile    pydoc2.7      pygettext3    python2       python3m
py3versions   pydoc3        pygettext3.6  python2.7     python3-qr
pyclean       pydoc3.6      pygmentex     python3       pythontex
pycompile     pygettext     pyhtmlizer    python3.6     pyversions
```

Comment: Don't clean up. Use `python3`, and you should be good.

Comment: But, be very aware that both Python 2.7 and 3.6 are well outdated. Version 3.8 is the oldest supported (3.7 exists for about one month from now), and Python 3.11 is the most recent. If you can, see if you can install a more recent version.

Comment: Don't delete stuff just because you don't know what it does. Having all this stuff there isn't an issue. _If_ you are going to "clean up", ensure you actually understand what each thing does and whether it's needed by anything else before you remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it if those commands come by default in your system and you haven't installed them yourself, you should be very careful deleting them without further consideration. You have to keep in mind that on Linux, Python comes preinstalled on most Linux distributions. Certain elementary applications use Python to function, based on the fact that it is a standard. I recommend using Virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), this will save you many headaches in the future.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to install the latest version then.  Would I simply install the latest python release and not touch anything that have been previously installed?

Comment: You can do that. But you have to ensure that the new python is in your path.

Comment: Have done `make test` on `Python-3.11.3` but got the error shown below.  Could this problem be fixed ?

Comment: `/home/hagbard/Opstk/src/python/python-3.11.3/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c:118:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory   118 | #include <ffi.h>  compilation terminated.  Failed to build these modules: _ctypes`

Comment: Looks like something is missing. Those error are common when you are installing. I would say to have a look if `libffi-devel` is there, and try to install it if not.

Comment: Would I need to clear `Python-3.11.3` and call `configure` again ?

Comment: I don't think so